# How to delete a string from struct array

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, record

I'm doing a project for displaying the table of a soccer championhip. The part that I'm struggling with is the deletion of a club by entering his name. I have, for example, the following record:

```
struct soccer_table_properties
{
    char name[LENGTH];
    int gscored;
    int gconceded;
    int points;
};
```

If I enter the name club in order to delete it, I also delete his gained points, gol scored and conceded, but I can't figure that. Can You help me, please?

For the deletion part, I tried this implementation but it doesn't work.

```
do {
        printf("Enter the club name: \n");
        scanf("%s", club[i].name);

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            res = strcmp(club[j].name, club[i].name);
            if (res == 0){
                true = 1;
                strcpy(club[j].name, 0);
                i--;
            }
        }

        if (true == 0) {
            printf("wrong number \n");
        }
   } while (true == 0);
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried ? Not sure to get your problem. What do you call delete, free the memory ?

Comment: Please fix a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a array of structures.so to delete an element you must move all the elements to right of element i.e left shift all of them after the element.or else if are making it 0 to represent deletion then it should be fine.in the code use "0".